# mysql use json for comments or separate into table it self?

Tags: mysql, database

what is more efficient and more performance 
have array of objects or separate table

example

```
id 
date 
json (array of comments)
```

or

separate comments into table it self

```
id 
user 
comment
```

Comment: You can pack your entire data into a single JSON string. But if you want to build a relational database, every entity should have it's own table.

Comment: will i gain any thing using the json method or it's better to use relational way

Comment: See: [is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad). A JSON array is not much different from a comma delimited list.